# Trouble with table relationships within Access

Tags: database, ms-access, table-relationships

I am creating a project where Teachers enter a students coursework grades and it does various reporting on that data.

It is for a course where there are many units and within those units are many assessment objectives that the students can meet to either obtain a fail, pass, merit or distinction.

In the course there are 20 units but the school chooses a selection of these which they will teach to student. For example, my school chooses Unit 1, 3, 4, 7, 15, and 20.

Below is an image of what my current database looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glb7P.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/In7Rq.png

The problem i'm having is that access won't let me have multiple students which have have the same units. Also I want a separate table where I can have unit information such as name and description but I'm not sure how to do it?

Hopefully I've provided enough information, if not please don't hesitate to comment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a m to n relationship. Since those are a logical concept but not a physical concept, you need an additional junction table between the students and the units, so that you have

```
student <---- 1 : n ---> student_unit <--- n : 1 ---> unit
```

```
Table unit
----------
UnitID (PK)
Name
Description

Table student_unit
------------------
StudentID (PK, FK)
UnitID (PK, FK)
```

I would also make the difference between a table describing an assessment (`tlkpAssessment`) and another unction table between `tblUnit and`tlkpAssessment`. It allows you to assign the same assessment to different units. In these junction tables the ID columns are of type`Number, Long Integer`which matches the`Auto Number`column usually used for the IDs in the main tables. I also would set their`Required`property to`Yes`.

The prefix `tlkp` means "Lookup Table". I usually keep all table names in singular.

[image]

Comment: You are a star mate, will add to your reputation if I can work out how to. I'm pretty new round here :-)

Comment: On the left hand side of the answer, you can click the up- or down-arrows in order to upvote or downvote answers that you like or dislike and you can click the ckeck mark to mark the answer you think is the best one.

Comment: Although the database works I just realized I hadn't mentioned something that may have been important or I'm just not understanding or using the database correctly. 

Unit 1 could have say AO1, AO2, AO3, AO4, AO5 and Unit 3 could have A01, AO2, AO3, AO4 - will that database design still work for this?

Comment: The official documents which may help: 

http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/81821-unit-01-ict-skills-for-business-2010-assessment-coversheet.pdf

http://www.ocr.org.uk/images/81819-unit-03-digital-imaging-plan-and-produce-computer-graphics-2010-assessment-coversheet.pdf

http://www.ocr.org.uk/images/81823-unit-07-databases-design-and-use-2010-assessment-coversheet.pdf

Comment: Yes, this is why I have the two tables `tlkpAssessment` and `tblUnitAssessment`. The first table describes the assessment objects and the second assigns (or links) them to units. You can assign the same assessment (`tlkpAssessment`) to several units (`tblUnit`) through the junction table `tblUnitAssessment`. This is an m to n relation as well.